# Sharepoint 2010 Managed Metadata Service not there

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When I try to turn on the Managed Metadata Service in central admin, I don't see an option here  http://mycentraladmin:5555/_admin/ServiceApplications.aspx

I just see

Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application

Security Token Service Application

I also can't click on new

Answer (score 0):

I was using firefox, I should have been using IE.